# Parsing the WolframAlpha string result from the Oracalize __callback function into a usable format?

Tags: solidity, oracles, string, parser

I need to generate 10 unique random numbers between 0 to 100 in my smart contract.

For this I've decided to utilise Oracalize and one of the datasource called `WolframAlpha`. This is how I use it:

```
function loadNewRandomNumbers() public payable {
    oraclizeID = oraclize_query("WolframAlpha", "10 unique random numbers between 0 and 100");
}
```

I've deployed this to `Ropsten` test net and executed the `loadNewRandomNumbers` function and everything worked and I have the result from calling the wolfram alpha api datasource:

[image]

This is great so far; but I need to parse the `string` (json-like) response - so that I can use it; Ideally parse the response into an `uint array`.

How can I go about doing this? Is there a way parse the above string response into a usable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback function to separate the ID from the string, as in [this example](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/WolframAlpha.sol). Then you can use a tool like [solidity-util](https://github.com/willitscale/solidity-util) for parsing the string, as explained in [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27849/convert-string-of-integers-separated-by-a-delimiter-to-integer-array-in-solidity/27862).

Alternately Oraclize has a [parsing helper for JSON](http://docs.oraclize.it/#general-concepts-parsing-helpers), but I'm not sure if/how that works with Wolfram.